# Different syntax highlighting between inline and display-math in vim

Tags: vim, latex, vim-syntax-highlighting

I work on Vim with the solarized colorscheme.
In my .tex files, the syntax highlighting is different from `$...$` to `\[...\]`(or align environment).

The inline maths are in yellow, while the display-maths are in red. 
[image: As you can see here]

The mathzone seems recognized because i'm using a math context with Ultisnips that works.

Is this difference normal, and if it is, is there a way to highlight the both in the same way ?
I precise that i'm using Vimtex.

Comment: I am not sure since I never really used it much but I guess it is because when you do `$$` you are opening and closing the inline maths and leaving outside maths  sentence.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz you're welcome, thanks for you intervention, you're totally right  ! That said, any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a colorscheme inconsistency. Solarized defines highlight only for `texMathZoneX` but it does nothing with `texMath` or `texMathZoneY`. Hence the result. You can use other colorscheme or do some workaround. E.g.

```
augroup FixColors | au!
    autocmd ColorScheme solarized
        \ if &bg ==# 'dark' |
            \ hi texMath ctermfg=3 ctermbg=8 guifg=#b58900 guibg=#002b36 |
        \ else |
            \ hi texMath ctermfg=3 ctermbg=15 guifg=#b58900 guibg=#fdf6e3 |
        \ endif |
        \ hi! link texMathZoneX texMath
augroup end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would like to keep working with the solarized colorscheme. I put this lines in my .vimrc, and reopened my file, but the colors are still the same...

Comment: @Nnomuas Now it should work. Make sure you have `autocmd` before actual `colorscheme` setting.